# TextView + variable

Tags: java, android, textview

I've added to my TextView, after it has been modified with set.Text, a variable of type int (CONT1) 
How do I change only the color of the variable cont1? 
part of my code:

```
TextView cpu=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cpu);
cpu.setText("CPU: " + cont1);
```

I tried to put the value of cont1 in a new TextView and then add it to the first TextView in this way:

```
TextView cpu=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cpu);
TextView color=new TextView(this);
color.setText(cont1);
color.setTextColor(220);
cpu.setText("CPU: " + color);
```

but the output gives me strange values,how can I do to change only the color of the variable CONT1?

the problem is that I'm not merge two TextView

cpu.setText("CPU: " + color);
this code no work ,Why can not I merge two TextView?

Comment: if you do cpu.setText("CPU: " + color.getText()); should work but i dont think that it will transfer text color because that is just set to the textview, if you use my answer below with just one textview like in your first example you can get the results your looking for

Comment: let me know if i or @JRowan was of help to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to use **variable** and **format as HTML**, you can use:

**strings.xml:**

Important part is use `<![CDATA[` and variable `$s`.

`<string name="html_cdata_variable"><![CDATA[<b>CPU:</b>%1$s]]></string>`

**example.java**

```
    TextView color = findViewById(R.id.text_view_color);
    String variable = "some text in variable";
    color.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html_cdata_variable, variable);
```

When string contains CDATA it will return HTML entities back to string by `getString` and variable too.
So after retrive data by `getString` variable will be inflated, but HTML entities will not be trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

put the textviews in a linear layout and give gravity to children center, or align to each other in a textview and set the changeable colour string to your textview on the right..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#0000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cpu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CPU"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Changeabletextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="count"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this Html.fromHtml and format all of your strings

```
String text = "<font color=#ff0000>&hearts</font>
<font color=#ffd700>Wish List</font><font color=#ff0000>&hearts</font>";
cpu.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

**Example:**

```
String text = "<font color=#ff0000></font>CPU:<font color=#ffd700>" + CONT1 + "</font>";
cpu.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

and you cannot combine the two because TextView.setText(); does not take the parameter of TextView
if you use color.getText() it will get the text but not the color because the color is set to the TextView

Comment: yes, the same way you concatenate strings, like instead of WishList how it is in mine you would >" + CONT1 + "<

Comment: i put an example with CONT1 just change the colors to what youd prefer